# Perl - Directory Management on Different Operating Systems

Tags: perl

I am new in Perl. I am using the following command to remove a folder in Perl, under Windows:

```
system "del trash_folder";
```

But I intend to run the same script under `Unix` as well. I could get the OS name in the code and run a different command based on the OS. But is there no better way in Perl? I am thinking of possibly an API or so that is OS-ignorant.

Comment: `del trash_folder` doesn't delete a folder in Windows

Comment: You might be interested in `pathrmdir()` from [File::Copy::Recursive](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy::Recursive)

Comment: Or `remove_tree()` from [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny).

Comment: Core's [File::Path](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Path) has `remove_tree`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `del` command is never going to create a new directory, is it? :-)

- If you want to create directories, use the [`mkdir`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/mkdir) command.
- If you want to remove directories, use the [`rmdir`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/rmdir) command.

**Update:** In general, if you have a choice between using a Perl built-in function or an external command, then the Perl function will be the better choice. Firstly, your code will be more portable and, secondly, opening a sub-shell to run the external command will slow your program down.

Comment: @MakanTayebi: My update might be interesting to you.